# How do I change Spree commerce theme? How can I create my own

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I want to manually change everything about the style of spree, I don't want to use overides. I want to be able to get to html.erb and update by hand. I'm on linux and have installed Spree, where are they located? I was told it was under rvm, I dont have anything under rvm

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'spree', '3.0.4', :path => "lib/spree/"
gem 'braintree', '~> 2.48.1'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'

gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end



gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-stable'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create rails app and inside `lib` folder clone spree
then inside rails app `Gemfile` add `spree` with `lib` folder path 
something like

`gem 'spree' :path => "/lib/spree"`

then follow same proceduer, now if you will change in `lib` folder `spree` you can see changes in your app

Comment: When you say clone spree, what do you mean? Create a folder named spree and clone the html files into their? Where do I get these html files, I can't seem to find it. I'm using linux

Comment: @JamesRocky you will get entire code not only the view one :)

Comment: I've cloned spree to inside lib but I'm getting error `The path /lib/spree does not exist.` I've tried both `gem 'spree' :path => "/lib/spree"` and `gem 'spree', :path => "/lib/spree"`

Comment: could you paste gemfile ?

Comment: update: I was able to get to using `gem 'spree', '3.0.4', :path => "lib/spree/"` but I'm getting a dependence issue with spree. The error is `Could not find gem 'spree (= 3.0.4) ruby' in source at lib/spree/.
Source contains 'spree' at: 3.1.0.beta
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90716/discussion-between-jamesrocky-and-arv).

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/extensions_tutorial.html to create an extension for spree then can make changes by using deface https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/deface_overrides_tutorial.html
to override html changes in the theme. You can also use [Spree Fancy](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_fancy)
as reference.

Hope this solves your issue.

Thank you